# A word for someone willing to make sacrifices or drastic decisions

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking for a word for someone who is willing to make sacrifices or go to extreme lengths in order to get what they want. This is less about how badly they want something and more about how they are constantly prepared to make a tough decision. I'm looking for something more than just "determined" since its specifically focused on how willing they are to go to extremities if they feel its necessary.

Comment: There are a variety of words that come to mind depending on what your angle is.  You might call such a person "steadfast," "relentless," "unyielding," or even "cutthroat."  Ayn Rand would call such a person "objectivist."  If you're referring to a brave willingness to make sacrifices with the hope that it doesn't come to that, you might call that person a "risk-taker."

Comment: 'Uncompromising' may be what you want; it's mentioned in the duplicate.

Comment: Oh, another one came to mind: "tenacious."

Answer (score 2):

Such a person is [**committed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/committed) to a cause or course of action:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **2** : having made a pledge or commitment to someone (such as a romantic partner) or something (such as a cause)
> // *committed* partners
> // a *committed* parent/teacher
> // strongly *committed* to the fight for equal rights
> *also* : characterized by such a pledge or commitment
> // two people in a *committed* relationship

Also see the referenced [pledge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pledge):

> **6 a** : a binding promise or agreement to do or forbear
> **6 b (1)** : a promise to join a fraternity, sorority, or secret society
> **6 b (2)** : a person who has so promised

In the case of a *binding promise* as it relates to a pledge, it means that you will do so something even if it is difficult.

Answer (score 2):

**resolute**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resolute)

> Firm or determined; unwavering.

Answer (score 2):

[**unrelenting**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/unrelenting)

> **1.** Having or exhibiting uncompromising determination; unyielding
>
> **2.** Not diminishing in intensity, pace, or effort